# Horizontal lines randomly omitted?

Tags: support, editor

This one has been puzzling me for sometime now. For some reason, horizontal lines inserted into answers are randomly not being rendered properly:

[image]

The example above was taken from [Can't BER decode an RSA public key](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27904600/608639).

The problem does not always occur. For example, the same answer will have some rendered, and some not rendered. I've been working around it by double stacking them:

```
----------
----------
```

Does anyone know why this is happening? Or should I be doing something differently?

(This may be a recently introduced bug, or it may be something with Firefox. I'm going to list it as a support ticket until I know I'm using them correctly).

Comment: Unable to reproduce with FF ~~34.0.5~~ 35.0 (Windows 7).

Comment: Thanks  Jongware. I guess its an OS X thing. It was happening with the previous version of FF (34.0.5), and the current version of FF (35.0). I'll have to try it in another browser.

Comment: Seeing similar things with Chrome55/Win7, including @hinneLinks zoom solution. Wonder if this is a [subpixel rendering](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14242055/673991) issue, even when `<hr>` is styled `height: 1px`.

Answer (score 4):

I Just experienced the same, the hr was visible in the Edit-Preview, but in the Full Page it was invisible. It was there (i checked with Firebug and also with Chrome). #

Zooming in and out (back to 100%) fixed for me.

(Firefox 42.0, Win8)